# When a JasperViewer appear and I close it, the main frame/parent also closed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jasper-reports

When a `JasperViewer` appear and I close it, the main frame / parent also closed. How to prevent this?

This is my code..

```
 private void cmdprintidMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("report12.jrxml");
            String sql = "select * from db1 where Company LIKE '" + txtcompany.getText() + "%'";
            JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
            newQuery.setText(sql);
            jasperDesign.setQuery(newQuery);
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, conn);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
```

Answer (score 14):

Change this:
`JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);`

to `JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);`
This will work properly.

Answer (score 2):

No need to do anything, other than to call the alternative:

```
JasperViewer(jasperPrint, **false**);
JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, **isExitOnClose**);
```

The JasperViewer has alternative constructor/method call which receives boolean param: `exitOnClose`

I don't know if you've found your own way around but I think this is the best one.

Answer (score 2):

```
JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
```

You just have to pass false with `jasperviewer` so the parent window won't close.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
```

To:

```
JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
JasperViewer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

It would seem the`JasperViewer` is using `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` which will cause `System.exit(n)` to be called, thus ending the JVM.

By using `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` instead, only that frame is ended & disposed of.

Comment: Still having error. " non-static method setDefaultCloseOperation(int) cannot be referenced from a static context. Help meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee!